# What is the point of generic constraints when I can just use the union type?

Tags: typescript, constraints, union-types

I don't understand the point of using generic constraints because here we can achieve the same effect using union types.

```
//Generic Constraints:

class Person {
  constructor(public name: string) {}
}
class Customer extends Person {}
function echo<T extends Person>(value: T): T {
  return value;
}
echo(new Customer("a"));

//Union Type:

class Person {
    constructor(public name: string) {}
}

class Customer extends Person {}

function echo(value: Person | Customer): Person | Customer {
  return value;
}

echo(new Customer("a"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that in the case of union, you won't get the exact type that you have passed.
Generics:

```
// Customer
const a = echo(new Customer('a'));
```

Unions:

```
// Person | Customer
const a = echo(new Customer('a'));
```

In this specific case, generics are a better approach, but it's not always like that

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/PTDiFMDtwJwSwMYAIDCB7SBnALjAhnJNpgFwBQZCANnppkgAqyYZIDeZSSCGOMArgmxoYACgAO-AEZVESSHgC24Ekj6EA5gEp2AXzL7qtein440ymEnAAPbFAAm9JjBaQ9ZAGb9IQuK3AEAAs0AB4AFWs7R2dmDAA+UQA3PCp+FSRwrVVIji4YcGx+GHcUtPAAbgMyQJDRaAB3VDNhS1EAcjx2rS0qshBm80tKXmwkPCQAXmtgtHrwJtMh2A6unr6QAFVIf3dwgE9xFQoFZUxxPARwJAaMB1hPGmV2Tm4aOkY49zyublGBIQiCTSWTIU4ZdSQbQeLj6V5GD5LVqwKL2SBOT6uVhsOFcby+bC7GZ1MrpVQuNxIAA+g2RMGymMpNKRFhRP3yhWKpVS6SqsNeAwprGZLVZMHho3GU2Jc0atLFq26vWqQA)